# Use TStatusBar style and graphical effects within TTabSet control

Tags: delphi, controls, windows-xp, coding-style, compatibility

OS: Windows XP Pro SP3

Issue:

[image: Sorry for small image. Click to enlarge.]

> As you see - in left side is located StatusBar
>   Control ; In right side - TabSet Control.

What approach you would suggest to "copy" StatusBar style ( dynamic darkening of Top and Button ) into TabSet Control? Colour manipulations like *clNone* or *AlphaBlend* do not work ... and *TransparentColor* prop is not available either ...

Again I am too puzzled because there is a lot of options ( imho ) to choose from, but I do not know possible side-effects and level of compatibility in various Windows versions.

**Thank you very very very much** for any help.

> P.S. Sorry if it is hard to notice
>   issue I am experiencing in my little
>   image above, BUT if I would resize it, It
>   would lose quality and there might be
>   problems notice anything at all ..

---

**Rephrasing the Question**

StatusBar1 is Parent of TabSet1. Now it looks like this ( wrong ):

[image]

I must achieve this StatusBar1.Panels[0] and TabSet1 look ( correct ):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd9r9.png]

---

I also tried to use psOwnerDraw technique ( http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/statusbar_owner.htm ) for StatusBar1.Panels[0] and get this result:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a higher res image? I can't see anything.

Comment: Actually, the resolution is not a problem, the size is. The little white triangle to the right in the picture is the left part of the left tab of a TTabSet component.

Comment: The OP probably wants what we can see at the bottom of Delphi's editor window: The Code and History tabs appear to overlay the status bar.

Comment: I think the OP cares about the little XP-theme orange stripes on the tabs.

Comment: I think i need a new glasses.

Comment: Any other option for solution, guys?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want. My guess is that you want the gradient of the background TStatusBar to be visible behind the TabControl. You want the background of the TabControl to be transparent?

Comment: Ulrich clearly shows he understands what is the problem in the controls in this case. Read below ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned just because @Ulrich has divined you intent doesn't mean your problem is clear. @Ulrich is clearly using the force today.

Comment: Hehe :) Anyway - can you, David, suggest anything?!

Comment: @hx i still can't understand your Q!

Comment: David, made more clear question statement. Now there is no way anybody could not get idea of the problem(s) and therefore my question.

Comment: Pictures help, but your question is still pretty murky.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following in Turbo Delphi:

- Create a new VCL app.
- Drop a TStatusBar and a TTabSet on the form.
- Add the following OnCreate handler:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    StatusBar1.SimplePanel := True;
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'Hallo';
    TabSet1.Tabs.Add('Code');
    TabSet1.Tabs.Add('History');
    TabSet1.SetBounds(30, 0, TabSet1.Width, StatusBar1.Height); // Replace the 204
    TabSet1.ParentBackground := True;
    TabSet1.SoftTop := True;
    TabSet1.Style := tsSoftTabs;
    TabSet1.Parent := StatusBar1;
  end;
  ```
- Add XPMan to Unit1's uses clause.
- Run the app under XP. This gives me the following form:[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: I actually think he's asking about appearance (colors) not layout (in the status bar).

Comment: Sorry, Ulrich, I did not find this code making it look like it should ( as in your screen area shows ) :( All props you wrote already have been set ... that is why I desperately decided to ask here of possible solution. Still TabSet1 ignores ParentBackground property ...

Comment: Ulrich, yes, it is the result I need to achieve. RESULT: On blank project everything is displayed correct even without Manifest. On my current development project it is not ... seems like another internal functionality breakage liek I have with drag'n'drop ...

Comment: Could it be that the color of the TForm is different than the color of the TTabControl? If you set ParentBackground to True for the TTabSet it will take the color from its Parent which is the TForm, not the TStatusBar.

Comment: Mikael, color of what - background, tab, selectedtab, unselectedtab? What? And it is TabSet Control ( TTabSet class Object ) ;) I have clBtnFace in both StatusBar and TabSet BackgroundCOlor props ...

Comment: I clearly do not understand what the problem is. I'm sorry. Ulrich example looks good to you right? What is the problem with yours?

Comment: Problem is what is not clear to me too, that is why I am consulting here. :) The current situation is: I get correctly displayed StatusBar and Tabset on BLANK NEW Project, same as Ulrich forms screenshot. I just drop all controls on from, paste code in oncreate event and run app and everything is as it should be; BUT - with my currently developed application I have wrongly displayed StatusBar and TabSet, as You should see in my own screen-shot ( area ). It feels like that there is issue when the Background is painted w/o relaying on TabSet1.ParentBackground := True prop.

Comment: @HX: Do you have the issue on all forms in your project - even on a newly created form class?

Comment: @Ulrich: No, it happens only on general form. On other forms ( TAboutBox ) this issue do not occur. Maybe There is some prop that affects it or some Windows Message handling can cause this bug?

Comment: @HX: Then I would try to make a copy of a form class that exhibits the problem, add it to a new project (or the original project if necessary) and remove components until the issue disappears. The last removed component would be my first suspect for further investigation.

Comment: @Ulrich, yes, I think I have no choice other than your suggestion. Thanks for assistance, college! I will report back asap.

Comment: Noo, there is some other problem. Maybe There is brute-force way to do the drawing/painting to ensure it is done correctly???

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic ways to accomplish this:

1. Do it the way that the control you're copying does it, which means, invoke the XP Theming engine.  You should be aware if you do it this way, that this effect is conditional, and only shown on systems that (a) support and (b) have themes enabled, so any user who has chosen the Windows Classic Theme (Windows 2000 era look and feel) will not see it.
2. Write some code to do the effects yourself.  In this case, a bitmap that is carefully painted into a region on top of an owner-drawn tab. This will give you a consistent application look, but will be ignoring the users perhaps-intentional-perhaps-unintentional preferences on how the application should look.

Obviously there are tradeoffs in both approaches.